# CARBONE.IO Conditional display (ifEQ)

Tags: if-statement, templates, conditional-statements

I'm using Carbone to generate PDF with variables.

I need to make a conditional display. If a product have a specific category I need to display an information.

I tried to make the condition with **ifEQ**, **show** and **showBeggin // showEnd** but it does'nt work.

```json
// My JSON 
const json = {
 shopping : {
  sales :[
   {
     product_name: "Apple",
     product_price: 2,
     product_category: "fruits",
     comment: "",
   },
  {
     product_name: "Coke",
     product_price: 3,
     product_category: "soda",
     comment: "",
   },
   {
     product_name: "Cucumber",
     product_price: 1.5,
     product_category: "vegetable",
     comment: "",
   }, 
   {
     product_name: "Vodka",
     product_price: 15,
     product_category: "Alcohol",
     comment: "Dangerous for health, prohibited at least 18 years old",
   }, 
 ] 
}
}
```

What I made on my document :

| State |
| --- |
| {d.shopping.sales[i].product_name} {d.shopping.sales[i].product_category(“Alcohol”):showBeggin} Information {d.shopping.sales[i].comment}, {d.shopping.sales[i].product_price}, {d.shopping.sales[i].produt_name}{d.shopping.sales[i].product_category::showEnd} |
| {d.shopping.sales[i+1].product_name} |

Thank's for help !

Answer (score 1):

Your example got a couple of errors, some fixes to do:

- it is missing the `ifEQ` just before the `showBegin`
- if the ifEQ argument is a string, it must be wrap with single quotes
- `showBeggin` should be written `showBegin`
- the last `showEnd` should be preceded by only one colon.

Here is your template with all corrections:

| State |
| --- |
| {d.shopping.sales[i].product_name} {d.shopping.sales[i].product_category:ifEQ('Alcohol'):showBegin} |
| Information {d.shopping.sales[i].comment}, {d.shopping.sales[i].product_price}, {d.shopping.sales[i].produt_name}{d.shopping.sales[i].product_category:showEnd} |
| {d.shopping.sales[i+1].product_name} |

The conditional block documentation has been improved a lot, to get more examples: https://carbone.io/documentation.html#conditioned-output

Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) Unfortunately, I am not working on the project anymore. I can’t try your solution :/

Comment: You are welcome, it alright don't worry, it will help other people :)